# com.android.support:appcompat throwing error

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my gradle file , i tried forcing it to use the same version using com.android.support.customtabs:27.1.1 but still the problem persists.
Please help , I'm am new to Android Studio

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.spars.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i get the following error:
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Remove Build Tools version and sync project
Affected Modules: app

Comment: If you target API 28, you need to use the 28.x.x support libraries.

Comment: even if i downgrade it to v27 the problem is still there

Comment: You haven't actually specified the error.

Comment: what errors you are facing?? You should share errors log

Comment: i just added the error part ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any google services then as per docs you need to add the fire-base dependency:

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core as a dependency for Firebase
>   services to work as expected.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2'
```

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

About the **compile** keyword warning, this one is now obsolete. So from what I can see in your gradle file, in the **fileTree** line replace **compile** to **implementation**:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

And finally, for the **Android SDK Build Tools** warning, remove the **buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"** line, this is no longer necessary. From now on gradle will resolve and use the correct build tools.

And a final note, take into account that the **com.android.support** libraries are now deprecated, you should migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).